# Where is "vino-preferences" storing its config properties

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, vnc

I try to set up VNC server "vino" without a X-Session from command line on my Raspberry Pi. I do not want to use a shared X11Session over SSH and so on.

So, currently I am stucked within the fact that I do not know where the tool "vino-preferences" is storing its preferences.
I know that the tool is using "gconf" to read and set the configuration properties.

If I execute the tool "vino-preferences" within a created X-Window (Yes, I have a output device, a plugged keyboard and mouse at the Pi) and change some settings there and run

```
find / -not -path "/proc/*" -not -path "/sys/*" -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort
```

to find out which files have changed there is nothing relevant.

So, where the hell is the tool reading its properties? The set properties are applied because if I deactivate the "Allow other users to use this Desktop" option I am not able to connect anymore with a VNC client.

Downloading the sources of "vino" I found a file called "org.gnome.Vino.gschema.xml" with this content:

```
<schemalist>
  <schema id='org.gnome.Vino' path='/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/'>
    <key name='enabled' type='b'>
      <summary>Enable remote access to the desktop</summary>
      <description>
        If true, allows remote access to the desktop via the RFB
        protocol. Users on remote machines may then connect to the
        desktop using a VNC viewer.
      </description>
      <default>false</default>
    </key>
...
```

So maybe this file must be used somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Yo can try with `gsettings` if you want to access via shell. If you have not it installed, they are in `libglib2.0-bin` package.

- Yo can see all config keys with:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
  ```
- And if you want to change the options it is possible doing:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.Vino view-only true
  ```

New settings will work once vino is restarted.